# Why CKEDITOR.replace not working in 2023?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I just downloaded CKEditor to use the WYSIWYG editor on my website, but this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form>
        <textarea name="body" id="body">
           This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
           CKEDITOR.replace('body');
        </script>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this error

[image: error]

Comment: What is "this error"? Please share all details in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Maybe putting the error message into your favorite search engine could help?

Comment: I don't know what this error is. This is my first time getting this error, This code was working before.

Comment: Please share the error from the console **in text form**

Comment: Error code: cloudservices-no-token-url. ckeditor.js
For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#cloudservices-no-token-url ckeditor.js
Error code: invalid-lts-license-key. ckeditor.js
For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#invalid-lts-license-key

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, did you try to use the link that you've posted? As far as I see, it contains a clear explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message contains a link with a good explanation. Taken from https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#invalid-license-key:

> Description: The editor license key for the LTS (“Long Term Support”) version is missing or invalid. That version of the editor is only available under commercial terms (“Extended Support Model”) for anyone looking to extend the coverage of security updates and critical bug fixes.

Keep in mind that CKEditor 4 is EOL since June 2023. You should either use a (payed) license key, use the last CKEditor version without the warning (v4.22.1), or update your application to use CKEditor 5 (which is available since years)